# libGDX compiles only a Black Screen

Tags: java, android, macos, libgdx

**SOLVED!!!** Seems the image wasnt in a proportionate size, eg, 64x64, 128x128

Made a basic Hello World and this compiled all good, but when I try and get a basic graphic to display, all that shows is blackness. basically following a tutorial word for word and it still seems to be doing this. Any ideas anyone?

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {

SpriteBatch batch;
BitmapFont font;
Texture mario;





    @Override
    public void create() {
        mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mario.jpeg"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(mario, 200, 200);
        batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Just realised there was an error code coming up. file name is definitely correct.

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/mario.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:142)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:112)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:104)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:30)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data/mario.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:563)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:218)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: batch.draw(mario, 200, 200); This renders your texture to (200, 200). How big is your window size?

Comment: Window size is set at 640x480

Comment: make sure that mario.png file is in the Data directory and not in the assets.

Comment: Yup, it's in the Data next to the default libgdx demo image

Comment: where do you use the mario.png image in your code? I could not find any statmente in your code that load or use the mario.png file?

Comment: I'm assuming the

mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mario.jpeg"));

and the 

batch.draw(mario, 200, 200);

do this. Still learning though so correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: does you have an image with name mario.jpeg in your assets folder?

Answer (score 3):

> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data/mario.png (Internal)

It can't find the image "mario.png" in the data folder. Make sure you have the image in the android asset folder (Android Project -> Assets -> Data -> mario.png) .

You may want to look into how to read stack-traces (Big long error report thing) it will save you lots of time in the future.

Edit: [Here is link for you on stack-traces](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/how-to-read-stack-traces-and-troubleshoot-your-own-plugins-by-yourself.32457/)

Comment: It's in that folder, even shows up on the left in the package explorer in assets>data_mario.png in both Android and Desktop

Comment: Is the file in the assets folder a .png or a .jpeg? In your code it says you want a .jpeg but the error is saying .png.

Comment: Code I copied was wrong =P Fix ended up being the resolution of the image.

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data/mario.png (Internal)
```

He couldn't find mario.png. I recommend, if you don't use an Assets folder, to create another source folder containing all of your resources. After that, you can call `Gdx.input.classpath(String classpath)` to load a file from the actual exported .jar, without having to hardcode the paths.